# mod_rewrite: rewriting existing directory with htaccess in it

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdirectory

how can I tell mod_rewrite that ALL existing directories should be rewritten?

I have an subdirectory with a .htaccess-File which rewrites too. When I go to domian.tld/sub_with_htaccess, Apache only reads the htaccess in "sub_with_htaccess" but do not read the .htaccess in / which is more important for me.

BUT: When I have a subdomain (sub.domain.tld) whose document root points on /var/www/domain-tld/sub_with_htaccess, I want that only the .htaccess in "sub_with_htaccess" decides what to do.

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the [RewriteOption](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions) directive in the htaccess file in the **sub_with_htaccess** directory:

```
RewriteOption Inherit
```

This will make it so rules from parent directories get appended **after** the rules in this htaccess file. If you are using apache 2.4, you can also use the `InheritBefore` option which will place the parent htaccess' mod_rewrite rules **before** the rules in this htaccess file.